# What is the equivalent directory for Laravel Windows?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel docs say Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory (or the equivalent directory for your OS) in your PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system. What is the equivalent directory for Windows?

Comment: What version of windows are you running? Why not just use the installer, it sets it up globally automatically? https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in  C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin

Answer (score 2):

`~` = Your user directory in linux so on windows it is simply `c:/Users/[yourname]` but everything else is the same. So look in `C:/Users/[yourname]/.composer/vendor/bin`

Comment: While that statement is generally true for other applications composer documentation says [otherwise](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home)

Comment: @Rangad you are correct, guess I've been going back and forth between my Mac and PC, I swore it was in `c:/users/[yourname]/.composer`